# Cannot Get Extras To Service :(

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm

Whatever I do I cannot get my extras from my activity to my service!!! It is vital to me and I am so frustrated at this point, I have tried every type of flag there is!!! Please help!I am using a PendingIntent and trying to pass the Extras from the intent to the pendingIntent and then to the service.

```
This is my code for the PendingIntent part.

 public void actionSetup(boolean activitycreated[],int buttonclicked[])
    {
        SharedPreferences data=getSharedPreferences("ACTIVITY_DATA",MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        int origin=Integer.valueOf(buttonclicked[0]);
        myintent[buttonclicked[0]]=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Handler.class);
        myintent[buttonclicked[0]].setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
        myintent[buttonclicked[0]].setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        myintent[buttonclicked[0]].putExtra("origin",origin);
        myintent[buttonclicked[0]].setAction(String.valueOf(origin));
        stuff[buttonclicked[0]]=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),buttonclicked[0],myintent[buttonclicked[0]],PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
              calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH));
              calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
              calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
              calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, data.getInt(buttonclicked[0]+"startimehour",1));
              calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, data.getInt(buttonclicked[0]+"startimeminute",1));
              calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
              if (data.getInt(buttonclicked[0]+"startimehour",1)>=12)
              {
                  calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);
              }
              else
              {
                  calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);
              }

              AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
              alarmManager.set(alarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),stuff[buttonclicked[0]]);
              Log.i("value of da origin",String.valueOf(origin));

            }


        }
```

Code for service

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Bundle exras=intent.getExtras();
        int origin=exras.getInt("origin");

      if(exras !=null ) {


          Log.i("AY", String.valueOf(origin));
      }
        SharedPreferences data=getSharedPreferences("ACTIVITY_DATA",MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

        boolean daysselected [] []=new boolean[8][7];

        boolean [] [] functionsselected=new boolean[8][2];

        for(int m=0;m<=7;m++)
        {
                functionsselected[m][0]=data.getBoolean("silent"+m,false);
                functionsselected[m][1]=data.getBoolean("bluetooth"+m,false);
        }

        Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
        int dayofweek=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        Handler.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        stopSelf();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);


    }
```

Comment: What are you seeing vs. what you expect?  Is your `Service` even being started?

Comment: Yea my service gets started.

Comment: Sorry, if you would like help you're going to have to provide more details about what you are seeing vs. what you expect.  I'd be surprised if your `Service` is actually getting started from the `PendingIntent` since the `PendingIntent` being created is a broadcast.  You'd need to have a `BroadcastReceiver` registered to handle that `Intent` and it could then trigger an `Intent` to start the `Service`.

Comment: I do have a broadcastreciever anyway I fixed the problem yesterday.